# Mongodb, web got stuck after inserting some data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every button is clickable and functional before I inserted data.

[image: insert data page]

Render update page after insert:

[image: then it looks like this]

But then whatever I click the Web got stuck:
[image: keep loading]

But data has already been inserted.

The insert code is here:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
// ...

router.post('/update', function (req, res, next) {
    var item = {
        result: req.body.books
    };
    db.collection('details-data').insertOne(item, function (err, result) {
        db.close();
    });
    res.render('update');
});
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `next` argument?

Comment: You're closing the database connection after inserting, that surely isn't going to help.